# How does While Loop timing work in C# w/ multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, while-loop

I have a isRunning boolean variable that can be updated from multiple threads.  I have a while loop that runs as long as isRunning is true.  Immediately at the start of the loop, it checks again to see if the boolean is true.  Conceptually, I can see a situation where the while loop sees isRunning as true and then another thread updates that value before the if statement gets processed.  In practice, I imagine the timespan in which isRunning would have sub milliseconds to change in order to ever hit the if statement.  To me, this feels like smelly code.

```
while(isRunning) {
       //isRunning gets updated by another thread??
   if(!isRunning) {
      //Will this ever get hit???
   }
 }
```

Can the if block ever get triggered? What sort of timespan is there between the execution of the while check followed immediately by an if check?  How would I go about experimenting with this?

Comment: "Can the if block ever get triggered?" - absolutely. the `while` condition is only checked at the beginning of the loop. If another thread can update the boolean at any time, then it's certainly possible that the loop starts with `isRunning` as true and `isRunning` becomes false before the if condition.

Comment: You might want to use a ManualResetEvent for your purpose

Comment: Your 'in practice' assumption is quite dangerous.

Comment: "What sort of timespan is there between the execution of the while check followed immediately by an if check?" You've left out a lot of code, in particular the body of the while loop and the code running in other threads. So it's difficult to say. However, all that needs to occur is a simple context switch, which is ultimately out of your control. In short - *it's possible*.

Comment: I agree that it's possible that `isRunning` becomes false before the if condition, but how tight is the timing for that to happen?

Comment: It's possible that optimizations mean that `isRunning` is stored in a CPU register, and therefore will *never* show as `false` on the other thread (an infinite loop). This code is completely not thread-safe, you need to use `Interlocked` for this kind of thing

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Nonblocking Synchronization - Memory Barriers and Volatility](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Memory_Barriers_and_Volatility)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various theoretical arguments can be made, but let's just try it. I won't be very careful, since that's not the point. The point is distinguishing whether hitting that `if` block is some astronomically rare event, or not.

For example:

```
static void Main()
{
    int IfBlockHitCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Thread runner = new Thread(RandomlyResetRunningFlag);
        IsRunning = true;
        runner.Start();
        while (IsRunning)
        {
            if (!IsRunning)
                IfBlockHitCount++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(IfBlockHitCount);
}

static volatile bool IsRunning;
static volatile int sink;

static void RandomlyResetRunningFlag()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int spinCount = r.Next(1000, 1000000);
    for (int i = 0; i < spinCount; i++)
        sink = 0;
    IsRunning = false;
}
```

I ran this a couple of times, and pretty high numbers are printed, typically just under 500 (ie just under half the time). From this I conclude that *yes, hitting that `if` block is likely*.

But why? I propose this explanation. Since the thread that is executing the busy-wait is doing basically two things:

1. Checking `IsRunning` in the condition of the `while`.
2. Checking `IsRunning` in the condition of the `if`.

There isn't really anywhere else that time is spent. Given a random-ish time at which `IsRunning` is first observed to be `false`, there is a decent chance of that being in either of those cases. If the thread was actually *doing* anything, that would change the outcome a lot. Which way it changes it, depends on *where* the thread was doing something:

```
while (IsRunning)
{
    // A
    if (!IsRunning)
        IfBlockHitCount++;
    // B
}
```

If more code was added in position A then it would become more likely to execute the `if` block. If more code was added in position B, it would become less likely to execute the `if` block.

To put it a different way: it's not really a question of how short the time window is, it's a question of how big it is in relation to the amount of time outside of that window. Even a short window can cover a lot of the total timeline, if nothing else is going on.

By the way `IsRunning` must be `volatile`, otherwise the whole question is moot. (and as a reminder for experts, C# `volatile` is *not* the same as C++ `volatile` and actually works for this kind of usage, although it is not necessarily recommended) I also made a volatile `sink`, in order to force that random-duration wait loop to actually do something, it would be bad if the loop got optimized away.